# Gstreamer nvcompositor in python

Tags: python, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

Can someone explain how I can make this pipline (that works in shell) to work in python and cv2.VideoCapture(gstr, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvcompositor \
name=comp sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 sink_0::width=800 \
sink_0::height=650 sink_1::xpos=800 sink_1::ypos=0 \
sink_1::width=800 sink_1::height=650 ! nvoverlaysink display-id=1 \
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw , width=(int)1600 , height=(int)1300 , format=(string)GRAY8 , framerate=(fraction)60/1' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1600, height=(int)1300, format=I420' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw, format=BGRx' ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)800 , height=(int)650' ! videoconvert ! comp. \
v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! 'video/x-raw , width=(int)1600 , height=(int)1300 , format=(string)GRAY8 , framerate=(fraction)60/1' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1600, height=(int)1300, format=I420' ! nvvidconv ! 'video/x-raw, format=BGRx' ! videoconvert ! 'video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=(int)800 , height=(int)650' ! videoconvert ! comp. -e
```

Comment: I have no idea if `VideoCapture` can do this - but question is if you really need `VideoCapture` for this. You can always run this command with `subprocess.run()`

Comment: I have been thinking about subprocess. But I need to be able to pause/run the image too. Also I had some issues with the processes that it was consuming too much CPU.